# Splitting a string by CRLF in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

SO I know that there are a few post like this already here, but those post don't seem to work for me.  My string contains '^' in it, and replace does not seem to like that character.  Because of this, SELECT * FROM `STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(@InbMsg,@CLRF,'|'),'|')`
does not seem to work  The example message is this:

```
'W^1^Wave1102^2^11 

H^12345678900987654321^OD1128263^MLO^7^Bill’s Order^98712391^N^A2^3^11

D^OGMens77162^123456789009^Y^4^Medium^Red^006134^000101^11728492'
```

When I run it through the previous statment, I just get 'W'.  Anyone know why?

Comment: what are you defining `@CLRF` as? what is the data type of the `@InbMsg`? are you sure that your line breaks are both Carriage Return and Line Feed characters?

Comment: Why are you using replace and not split directly? See  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9e6830b92685a726c69dc85421989ad2

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: Your code works fine for what you posted here. Perhaps you should post a fiddle so we are all on the same page. https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: For all of those who helped, thank you.  It was a situation of me beiong dumb.  I declared it as a varchar but didnt set a number for how big.

Comment: I take it you refer to @InbMsg in regard to the size of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace the newline between 11 and H and also between 11 and D.  You can replace the newline by looking for CHAR(10) then replace it with '^'. Then you can now split the rows using '^' as delimiter.

```
select * from STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE('W^1^Wave1102^2^11 
H^12345678900987654321^OD1128263^MLO^7^Bill’s Order^98712391^N^A2^3^11
D^OGMens77162^123456789009^Y^4^Medium^Red^006134^000101^11728492',CHAR(10),'^'),'^');
 

Sample result:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0dc110c889af42a8b02096eedee3c393

value
W
1
Wave1102
2
11 
H
12345678900987654321
OD1128263
MLO
7
…
10 rows of 26
```

CHAR(10) is ascii value for  New Line / Line Break for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

It was a situation of not using varchar correctly.  Make sure to declare variables correctly!  ```SELECT * FROM STRING-SPLIT(REPLACE(@msg, @CLRF, ','),',') works in this situation!